# How to change the position of marker from a javascript function?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have to change the position of a marker on Google map from a javascript function. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

[You can use setPosition function of the marker class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

```
function changeMarkerPosition(marker) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.397, 140.644);
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
}
```

Comment: what if we have multiple markers and we want to update a specific marker based on Id ?

Comment: @UsmanIqbal You pass the marker object you want to move to the changeMarkerPosition function

Answer (score 2):

First off you must store the marker in an array when you create it so you can have access to it afterwards.
Then change the position with `marker.setPosition()` as solidrevolution mentioned.

Comment: You don't have to store it in an array at all

Answer (score -9):

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```