# Google marker disappearing when use setPosition to change position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple google maps , and I am creating a simple map with a marker with the below code:

```
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('hr-map');
        // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
        // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.098353, 55.156124),
            map: map,
            title: 'HR',
            scrollwheel: false,
            icon: 'images/res/map-marker.png'
        });
```

Now all I wanted to do is move the marker from the center of the map to somewhere below the center, I googled and check the below two links, one is a SO question and the fiddle demonstrating changing the marker position.

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingstiff/rsp22/)**

**[SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818129/how-to-change-the-position-of-marker-from-a-javascript-function)**

Now I used the same line of code used in the fiddle and also in the SO thread and wrote the below line of code:

```
    marker.setPosition(google.maps.LatLng(25.098353, 55.156124));
```

But adding the above line of code actually makes the entire marker disappear. So now my code looks line below:

```
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('dynamic-hr-map');
        // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
        // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.098353, 55.156124),
            map: map,
            title: 'Dynamic HR',
            scrollwheel: false,
            icon: 'images/res/map-marker.png'
        });

        marker.setPosition(google.maps.LatLng(25.098353, 55.156124));
```

So well why is my marker disappearing in the first place ? Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the new keyword. You need to create a new instance of LatLng object before using it.

```
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(25.098353, 55.156124));
```

Comment: thanks .. iám going to accept this answer and go punch myself in the face !